# __mro__ attribute missing on issubclass check when implementing protocols

Tags: python-3.x

As a thought experiment, I'm working on implementing a dictionary with sorted keys. (This is to cement my understanding of the various protocols such as `Collection`, `Iterable`, `Sequence`, and friends, and how to implement them.)

Currently, I'm trying to implement `Iterable`. I have a very basic class that looks like this:

```
class SortedKeysDictionary:
    def __init__(self, dictionary = None):
        if dictionary:
            self._data = dict(dictionary)
        else:
            self._data = {}

    # Getter and setter

    def get(self, key):
        return self._data[key]

    def set(self, key, value):
        self._data[key] = value

    # Iterable

    def __iter__(self):
        # Return a generator that sorts data
        for item in sorted(self._data.__iter__()):
            yield item
```

This seems to work fine, because this test passes:

```
s = SortedKeysDictionary({"b": 1, "a": 2})
for item in s:
    print(item)
```

However, when I test if the instance actually implements the protocol, like so, Python raises an error:

```
s = SortedKeysDictionary()
assert issubclass(s, Iterable)
```

The stack and exception is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\abc.py", line 207, in __subclasscheck__
    ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 255, in __subclasshook__
    return _check_methods(C, "__iter__")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 73, in _check_methods
    mro = C.__mro__
AttributeError: 'SortedKeysDictionary' object has no attribute '__mro__'
```

I have some understanding of the MRO and abc.collections, but I'm not clear on why this error is raised (or how to resolve it). For example, changing my class definition to `SortedKeysDictionary(Iterable)` doesn't seem to resolve it.  For the MRO itself, I checked what `{}.__mro__` returns, and I get an `AttributeError` that `__mro__` doesn't exist.

What am I missing here? Is my class flawed in some way, or is my test-case invalid?

For reference, I went through a Python course where we implemented something similar; we also wrote unit tests for things like `issubclass(x, Sequence)` and they seemed to succeed after implementing the required protocols.

This also seems to raise regardless of which container protocol or subclass I test `issubclass` for.

Comment: I think `issubclass()` is expecting you to pass in classes. You're passing in an instance and a class. Maybe try `issubclass(SortedKeysDictionary, Iterable)` (or `isinstance(s, Iterable)`)?

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is an embarrassing mistake. Since I can't delete my question now, I might as well self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered in parallel with @glibdud, this is due to a simple typo. `issubclass` expects (in my use-case) two meta classes as arguments, not a class instance and a meta class.

To resolve this, I simply changed `issubclass(s, Iterable)` to `issubclass(SortedKeyDictionary, Iterable)` and I get `True` as expected.

Comment: 3.6. My bad, I mixed up `Iterable` and `Container` because I was testing both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The `__mro__` is an attribute specific to the class, so you cannot use `issubclass` on an instance. Instead you can use `isinstance`.

```
isinstance(s, Iterable) # True
```

I also find this has the advantage of clarity as it literaly asks: *is the instance s iterable?*

Comment: IMO this is less understandable than `issubclass(SortedKeyDictionary, Iterable)` especially given my goal (make a class that implements some protocols). Still, this is a valid answer.

Comment: isinstance exists exactly to check that the object's class is a subclass, I am not sure it is less understandable since it's its exact purpose

Comment: Wait, did you comment before or after my edit, it seems close

Comment: Sure, sorry for the confusion!